# Gabriel's horn and General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

Is there anything in GR that involves [Gabriel's Horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_horn)?

This idea came to me when I met Flamm's paraboloid. If we take Schwarzschild metric at constant time and $\theta=\pi/2$, we get
$$ds^2=\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2+r^2d\varphi^2,\tag{1}$$
which is also the induced metric in a Flamm's paraboloid $z(r)=2\sqrt{r_s(r-r_s)}$, with $r$ the distance to the axis in cylindrical coordinates.

Now my question is if Gabriel's Horn could be something anologous to Flamm's paraboloid to another spacetime, in the sense that the metric induced in
$$z(r)=-\frac{a^2}{r},\tag{2}$$
which is
$$ds^2=\left(1+\frac{a^4}{r^4}\right)dr^2+r^2d\varphi^2,\tag{3}$$
could be related to some spacetime.

Comment: It all depends on what you call "space-time". Also, you should not take some random metric and ask whether it is a space-time, but rather the inverse thinking: taking the EFE and solving it to find a peculiar metric.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux actually I could insert any metric in EFE and see what is the $T_{\mu\nu}$ needed to have it.

Comment: Of course you can find y such that y=x by knowing x...

Comment: You can foliate a 3D Euclidean space with Gabriel's horns, meaning it is possible to define coordinates $(w,r,\phi)$ so that each section $w=\mathrm{const}$ has a geometry of Gabriel's horn. Likewise, there are many meaningful Lorentzian manifolds that would admit coordinate systems with 2D sections  $x_0=c_0, x_1=c_1$ with Gabriel's horn geometry.

Answer (score 2):

For a maximally rotating Kerr black hole with a=M the throat of the corresponding [Flamm's paraboloid](http://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=506#p506) does get infinitely long, see [Bardeen, 178:347-369, 1972](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?db_key=AST&bibcode=1972ApJ...178..347B&letter=.&classic=YES&defaultprint=YES&whole_paper=YES&page=347&epage=347&send=Send%20PDF&filetype=.pdf#page=7):

> Bardeen wrote: *"In the limit $\rm a→M$, the proper radial distance between $\rm r_{ms}$ and $\rm r_{mb}$ goes to infinity, as does that between $\rm r_{ms}$ and $\rm r_0$."*

[image: rotating black hole throat]